# Using induction to prove that $\sum_{r=1}^n r\cdot r! =(n+1)! -1$

Tags: summation, induction, factorial

> Use induction to prove that 
>   $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n r\cdot r! =(n+1)! -1$

I first showed that the formula holds true for $n=1$. 
Then I put n as $k$ and got an expression for the sum in terms of $k$. 
I then found the sum till the $(k+1)$th term by adding the $(k+1)$th term to both sides of the equation and compared it to the sum expression I get by plugging $k+1$ into the sum expression given in the question - they don't match.

Comment: TeX tip: use `\cdot` for centered dot, as in $2\cdot3=6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\begin{align} \\ (k+1)! -1 + (k+1)(k+1)!  &= (k+1)!(1 + k+1) - 1 \\&=  (k+1)!(k+2)-1\\&= ? \end{align}$$

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing! It simplifies to (k+2)!(k+1)! -1

Comment: I see... so the proof is complete, right ?

Comment: Oh wait a second, how does that simplify to (k+2)!(k+1)!-1 ? $$n!(n+1) = (n+1)!$$

Comment: shouldnt the sum be (k+2)! - 1? I am sorry if my questions seem silly, I just started induction.

Comment: yes, and thats exactly what you need to conclude the statement holds for $n = k+1$ because $$(k+2)! - 1   =  (\color{Red}{k+1} + 1)! - 1$$

Comment: typo, it simplifies to (k+2)(k+1)! -1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16873/discussion-between-ganeshie8-and-user140161).

Answer (score 6):

Also a neat way to solve it without induction $$\sum_{r=1}^nr\cdot r!=\sum_{r=1}^{n}(r+1-1)\cdot r!=\sum_{r=1}^n (r+1)!-r!=(n+1)!-1$$
Since all terms cancel out except $(n+1)!$ and $-1$

Comment: I agree with you that your way is neat :). +1