# Proving that $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k! \cdot k = (n + 1)! - 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Someone may have already asked this question, but I was not able to find it.

> Prove that
>   $$\sum_{k = 1}^n k! \cdot k = (n + 1)! - 1$$

I tried to use the method that is generally applied to geometric series, i.e. writing $S_n - \phi(\cdot)S_n = \dots$ in such a way that almost all terms cancel out. The problem is that in this case it does not work because there is nothing constant in the series' terms.

Comment: [Here it is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917367/using-induction-to-prove-that-sum-r-1n-r-cdot-r-n1-1) :)

Comment: @kingW3 Ahh thanks! Then this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: No problem,btw it looks kinda weird when you close your own question :P

Comment: @kingW3 Eheh it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove by induction that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{k}\cdot{k!}=(n+1)!-1$.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1}{k}\cdot{k!}=(1+1)!-1$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{k}\cdot{k!}=(n+1)!-1$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}{k}\cdot{k!}=$
- $\color{red}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{k}\cdot{k!}}+{(n+1)}\cdot{(n+1)!}=$
- $\color{red}{(n+1)!-1}+{(n+1)}\cdot{(n+1)!}=$
- $(n+1)!\cdot(n+2)-1=$
- $(n+2)!-1$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: You may want to incorporate this into the duplicate question so this one can be closed without losing the answer.

Comment: @AlexR: Thanks. How do I do that?

Comment: Either flag the question so a mod can merge the two or Copy Paste as a new answer in the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
See that
$$(n+2)! - (n+1)! = (n+1)(n+1)!$$
And use induction.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm not very good at induction, I should practice more.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(k+1)!=k!(k+1) \Rightarrow k!k=(k+1)!-k!$. Use this in your sum to find:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k!k= (2!-1!)+(3!-2!)+(4!-3!)+\cdots + (n+1)!-n!
$$
and eliminating opposite terms you have the result.